# Inno setup gives error "File already exists" when trying to install a document file

Tags: inno-setup

More specifically, **Inno Setup** tells me:
 An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory:
Setup was unable to create the directory
"C:\Users\Vacuumhead\Documents\Myprog\Docs\Pic-01.tiff"
Error 183: Cannot create a file when that file already exists
I think the relevant line from my source script is:

```
Source: "Pic-01.tiff"; DestDir: "{userdocs}\Myprog\Docs";
```

What I find most confusing is that a nearly identical line except for the program name and document name exists in another script for a different program that has been working for years.

I checked, and it is a certainty that the named file does not exist anywhere in the {userdocs} hierarchy.

Any clues will be most welcome.

Comment: Addendum: That source statement is in the [Files] section of the script.

Comment: Did you actually check that when you remove that specific line, the problem goes away? Post [mcve]!

Comment: Yes, the problem didn't exist before I added the given line to the installer project, and it runs fine when I remove that single line. I've tried a number of variations, with different source files and different target files but the same directory structure. In all cases, it seems that I am simply unable to create the "Myprog" directory inside the {userdocs} directory. It will take a little while to create a minimal and verifiable example, but I'm on it.

Comment: Some users of my installer are experiencing the very same issue but I'm installing to '{userappdata}'. Didn't find any solution yet, wish someone could help.

Comment: I've found that my installer works fine on every computer except my own development system. So there's probably something odd going on with the file system on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this occur where an extra \ had been added to the end of the line:

```
    Source: "C:\foo\foobar\*"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\foo\foobar\";
```

What then happened was that the installer created a folder with the name of one of the files in the foobar folder, with that file placed within that folder. It didn't happen on all computers that I tried it on. Quite why that is, I'm not sure.